# A futuristic book I am sure was titled "Grandfather Bank"

Tags: story-identification

I read a book many years ago, I am positive the title was "Grandfather Bank" but it was a long time ago and my memory has obviously become faded. The cover of the book showed the silhouette of a man standing in front of a large yellow/gray building.

The book involved people being fitted with ID Chips and under constant monitoring by the government. The protagonist is homeless and has never worked, never used money, never bought food or drugs from stores, but one day a woman (a friend I think) comes to him with an illness and passes out. He does not want her to die so he goes to a pharmacy to buy her some medicine, which then causes his name to flash up on the system and he is hunted by the government.

*WHAT I CAN REMEMBER*

The protagonist is middle aged and white, he wants nothing to do with anyone or anything and a lot of the first chapter is his struggle with helping the woman who comes to him for aid. In the final chapters of the book the protagonist becomes a really powerful being capable of re-sculpting the universe, the book is read from his point of view throughout the book.

It is a mature novel and involves violence and swearing.

The book must have been published around 1990 maybe even before as i read it from a young age. roughly from 1999 on-wards.

I REALLY REALLY need to read this book again but I cannot find it, could anyone please help me find this book?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/152708/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This is "[**Stepfather Bank**](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2533188.Stepfather_Bank)" by D.C. Poyer.

> In 2110, the Bank has taken over. This super-corporation rules the
>   world with credit and controls a seemingly perfect Earth. Outrageous
>   Managhan Burlew, poet of anti-Bank rhymes and grandmaster of
>   beat-the-Bank scams, is the only man still free--the champion the
>   Earth is waiting for.

[image]

Comment: YES YES YES YES!!!

Thank you so much i have been searching for this book for years. how did you find it?!

Comment: @nyronmorrison - Bank is an unusual word to have in a book title. I searched on isfdb for that word, then scrolled down through the 186 matches. Having discounted "*The Ghost from the Grand Banks*", this was the only other book with a family-member related word; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=bank&type=Fiction+Titles

Comment: You sir are a genius! I have been searching for this book for 5 years and you found it in 5 minutes.

Comment: @nyronmorrison - I can only apologise for the delay. I shall try to do better next time.

Comment: 5 minutes?!  You, sir, are clearly slowing down in your old age :)